# Finding product in Ebay title listings

Tags: c#

Trying to find a way to pull certain products out of Ebay listings I give my program.

For example, if I feed it

```
"As New iPhone X 64GB White Free Shipping & Case"

It would pull "iPhone X" or "iPhone X 64GB"
```

Anything to identify it as an actual product, but I want to do it to ANY product I feed it so setting keywords to look for is probably redundant? I have about 100000 previous listings in my database that I could possibly use to reference?

I was looking at SpaCY to try learn some NER but I don't really know python nor do I want to recreate my whole program for this function.

Any advice is appreciated.

Edit:
More examples of what I"m trying to do.

```
"iPhone X New" == "iPhone X"
"Cracked Samsung S20 Free Ship" == "Samsung S20"
"iPhone 6" == "iPhone 6"
"Nintendo Switch Lite Bundle" == "Nintendo Switch Lite"
"Brand New Apple Airpods" == "Apple Airpods"
```

Basically when I feed it a listing title I want to beable to pull a product out of it if there even is one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question is all about the form that the text takes that you are feeding it. Could you please post at least 10 or 20 examples of the various strings you expect to see? Is the product always between the strings "As New " and "White Free Shipping & Case"?

Comment: Hey I added some more examples, let me know if I'm not being specific enough, cheers.